# Wordpress sends request to wrong api url

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have Wordpress admin panel and rest api on separate subdomain (`api.blog.com`), site uses Wordpress only as API and has url `blog.com`.

I have settings `WP_HOME = blog.com` and `WP_SITEURL = api.blog.com`

I upgraded Wordpress 5.2.4, and after saving post in console I see that WP sends ajax request to site, not to api `https://blog.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/10946?_locale=user` and of course I get error, because there is no route on this domain.

Why does WP send request to home url? How can I fix it? Before the new version all were ok..

Of course, I can write rewrite urls from `https://blog.com/wp-json/` to `https://api.blog.com/wp-json/` on my nginx and set CORS headers, but as I think it's bad way.